# Check radio buttons status in Recycle View Adapter and applying changes to it from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, radio-button, radio-group, oncheckedchanged

In my MainActivity method checkAnswer and showSolution are have to be modified because I added RecycleView adapter to the project and moved all view items to the QuestionAdapter. I do not understand how should I check status of rbGroup radio buttons using isChecked in QuestionAdapter and pass its id to MainActivity.
I tried to check this: [Radiogroup in recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476951/radiogroup-in-recyclerview)
but it is still unclear to me what steps should i take next. 
Can someone give me basic instruction, what steps should be taken in modifying my project from now.
Still can't find answer or tutorial for handling radio button list in Recycle view. How to check radio button status using interface from MainActivity?

Made some updates as was suggested. Do not understand how should i modify showSolution method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public QuestionAdapter adapter;
public ArrayList<Question> questionList;
private int questionCountTotal;
private long backPressedTime;
private int score;
private int questionCounter;
private Button btnConfirmNext;
private boolean answered;
private Question currentQuestion;
private TextView tvQuestion, tvScore, tvQuestionCount, tvCountdown;
public QuizDbHelper dbHelper;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnConfirmNext = findViewById(R.id.confirm_button);
    tvCountdown = findViewById(R.id.count_down);
    tvScore = findViewById(R.id.text_view_score);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new QuestionAdapter(this, questionList);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    dbHelper = new QuizDbHelper(this);
    questionList = dbHelper.getAllQuestions();
    questionCountTotal = questionList.size();
    Collections.shuffle(questionList);

        prepareQuestion();

    btnConfirmNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkAnswer();
        }
    });

}


private void prepareQuestion() {
    adapter = new QuestionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), questionList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    if (questionCounter < questionCountTotal) {
        currentQuestion = questionList.get(questionCounter);

        answered = false;
        btnConfirmNext.setText("Confirm");

    } else {
        finishQuiz();
    }
}


//How should I handle it in onbindViewHolder

private void checkAnswer() {
    answered = true;
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    RadioButton rbSelected = findViewById(rbGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    int answerNb = rbGroup.indexOfChild(rbSelected) + 1;

    if (answerNb == currentQuestion.getAnswerNB()) {
        score++;
        tvScore.setText("Score: " + score);
    }
    showSolution();
}

//How should I change state of the items in recycle view

private void showSolution() {
    rb1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    rb2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    rb3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    rb4.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    switch (currentQuestion.getAnswerNB()) {
        case 1:
            rb1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        case 2:
            rb2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        case 3:
            rb3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        case 4:
            rb4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
    }

    btnConfirmNext.setText("Finish");

}
```

QuestionAdapter

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

public ArrayList<Question> questionList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvQuestion, tvScore, tvQuestionCount, tvCountdown;
    public RadioGroup rbGroup;
    public RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4;



    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        tvQuestion = view.findViewById(R.id.question);
        rbGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radiog_group);
        rb1 = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_button1);
        rb2 = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_button2);
        rb3 = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_button3);
        rb4 = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_button4);
    }
}


public QuestionAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Question> questionList) {
    this.questionList = questionList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.question_card, parent, false);


    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Question question = questionList.get(position);
    holder.tvQuestion.setText(question.getQuestion());
    holder.rb1.setText(question.getOption1());
    holder.rb2.setText(question.getOption2());
    holder.rb3.setText(question.getOption3());
    holder.rb4.setText(question.getOption4());

    holder.rbGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int i) {

// How can I handle Check status here and pass it to main activity?

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return questionList.size();
}
}
```

**UPDATE.**
 After adding interface to my QuestionAdapter and apllying changes to constructor and other parts, my checkAnswer in MainActivity looks like this

```
    private void checkAnswer() {
    answered = true;
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    adapter = new QuestionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), questionList, new QuestionAdapter.OnItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelect(int position) {
           if (position+1==currentQuestion.getAnswerNB()){
               score++;
               tvScore.setText("Score: " + score);
           }
        }
        });
    showSolution();
}
```

Now what should I do with my showSolution method?
It seems like after checkAnswer i should send information back to QuestionAdapter and do setTextColor there. Probably i went wrong way...

[image: MainActivity]

Answer (score 4):

you can do this by using interface.

create an Interface like this:

```
public interface OnItemListener {
    public void onItemSelect(int position);
}
```

then in your adapter change the constructor like this:

```
  QuestionAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Question> questionList, OnItemListener 
  onItemListener) {
        this.onItemListener = onItemListener;
        this.questionList = questionList;
    }
```

and add this line in your onCheckedChangeListener

```
            onItemListener.onItemSelect(position);
```

like this:

```
holder.rbGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int i) {

        // How can I handle Check status here and pass it to main activity?
        onItemListener.onItemSelect(position);
        }
    });
```

then in your activity add this where you define the adapter(its another way to define adapter, you can also use your own way just remember to add the interface like this (new OnItemListener...)):

```
 dbHelper = new QuizDbHelper(getApplicationContext(), questionList, new 
 OnItemListener({

            @Override
            public void onItemSelect(int position) {
             // handle your check state of adapter item here
            }

        });
```